# Notation issue in Increments of a Random Walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, random-walk

Okay so a Symmetric Random Walk (from a coin toss experiment) is defined as:

$M_k$ = $\sum_{i=0}^k X_j$ , k=1,2,3...

Where $X_j$ takes the values -1 or 1 for Tails and Heads

Then they say that the increments,

$M_{k_1}$ = ($M_{k_1}$ - $M_{k_0}$), ($M_{k_2}$ - $M_{k_1}$), .... ($M_{k_m}$ - $M_{k_{m-1}}$)

are independent.

Stupid question, but I just want to clarify what $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$... are. 
Are the equal increments of k? i.e if $k_1$ is 3, then $k_2$ is 4 and so on? Or is it something else?

Comment: Any increasing sequence will do.

Comment: So if $k_1$ is 3, then $k_2$ can be 5 and $k_3$ can be 9 and so on with no pattern?

Comment: Yep. The increments will be independent regardless.